# Configurar o JDK no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, configuração

Preciso configurar o caminho do JDK no Android Studio via terminal sem acesso root para um script. O computador tem o JDK/JRE 7, tentei alterar o valor de algumas variáveis: PATH, JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, STUDIO_JDK, ... .

No terminal o jdk 8 funciona alterando o valor do PATH, mas quando abro o Android Studio ele só reconhece o JRE.

[image: JRE 8]

Graficamente via Project Structure eu consigo mudar o JDK, mas preciso que seja via CLI.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém sabe?

Comment: Ate onde sei quando altera o PATH pelo terminal, normalmente é temporário, o PATH é alterado somente para aquela janela/instancia do terminal, por isso não efeta o Android Studio. Para ser permanente acho meio dificil sem root.

Comment: O PATH alterado dessa forma é temporário, mas isso não tem relação na influência com o Android Studio, pois o que conta é como está na hora e a ideia do script é sempre alterar antes de abrir.

Answer (score 0):

O Android Studio usa a varíavel JAVA_HOME para obter a versão do Java. Você precisa utilizar o comando abaixo informando o seu respectivo local do Java:

```
export set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

Esse caminho do `default-java` não contém o Java 8, você vai precisar instalá-lo. Para a instalação, siga o [manual](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/).

Comment: Eu havia alterado essa variável, mas isso só faz o Android Studio reconhecer o jre, o JDK não.

Comment: Mas você colocou com o caminho do JDK? Se colocar com aquele default vai apontar pra um JRE mesmo.

Comment: Coloquei, tanto que quando coloco o valor da variável JAVA_HOME no campo JDK Location da GUI funciona.